# pkg_resources.resource_filename: how to return fully qualified shared library name?

Tags: python, shared-libraries, setuptools, pkg-resources

With Anaconda Python3.5 on Darwin, the following function

`import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.resource_filename('icqsol', 'icqLaplaceMatricesCpp')`

will return something like

`'//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/icqsol-0.3.19-py3.5-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/icqsol/icqLaplaceMatricesCpp'`

whereas what I need is

`'/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/icqsol-0.3.19-py3.5-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/icqsol/icqLaplaceMatricesCpp.cpython-35m-darwin.so'`

Note the suffix **'.cpython-35m-darwin.so'** in this particular case. I believe setuptools automatically adds this suffix when using python 3.5 -- it is absent when using python 2.7.

Does anybody know how to return the fully qualified shared library so I can use

`import ctypes
sharedLibName = ...
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(sharedLibName))`

? Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

`SOABI` is the key you are looking for; returns `None` on python2 and the relevant extension bits on python3.5. I added the extension suffix as well, but not really sure how that works on python3.5 (on mine, `SHLIB_EXT` returns `".so"` for py27 and `None` for py3)

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version_info)
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=1, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> import sysconfig
>>> sysconfig.get_config_vars('SOABI')
['cpython-35m-darwin']
>>> sysconfig.get_config_vars().get('SHLIB_EXT', '.so')
'.so'
```